# Relation between orderliness quotient and overall profile (like priveleges, reputation points)

Tags: discussion

When StackOverflow was launched, there was a level of disorder. So, there was certain reputation points for privileges to a user. With time, StackOverflow has evolved to become more organized. However, there has not been any reduction in reputation points for privileges. Is there any link between the orderliness quotient and reputation points?

Comment: I don't understand this question. What is an "orderliness quotient"?

Comment: I haven't the remotest clue what you're asking. Maybe my orderliness quotient is too low.

Comment: @NeerajT: Perhaps it is not as clear to others as it is to you, and it might help if you gave examples of "disorder," and how one would measure "orderliness."

Comment: @ChristianTernus Have you been neglecting your orderliness quotient again? You really need to raise it to fully appreciate meta

Comment: +1 for the idea to record stats of users and base the reputation requirements of privileges on those (either automatically, or manually - probably already done manually to some extent). Everything else in the question is ... unnecessary.

Comment: You are assuming that users will, indefinitely, help moderate the site once they reach enough reputation to do so. That assumption does not hold. Instead, the community is always in flux and new members with the motivation and ability to moderate are always needed, *especially* when a site grows.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is other way round, if a site is organized then users can focus more on adding good content thus their reputation goes up. The orderliness of a site attracts not only good content but also experts who now put more effort in providing good answers.

My point of view is that with the passage of time a consensus forms between the most active/committed users, on how the site should be moderated. The community of that site comes to a collective understanding about what content would be good/bad for their site (obviously under the umbrella of Stack Exchange guidelines). For example, some sites do allow a certain degree of subjectivity as compared to Stack Overflow which is now very strict on subjective posts (a couple of years back this was not the case).

When users know about the norms, bad/off-topic content gets removed from the site and users focus on posting good questions/answers, other members find that content useful thus overall reputation points go up (using upvotes and bounties).

I don't think that Stack Exchange has any machine learning system in place when it comes to the reputation points mechanism.